# What does this declaration mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

Consider the declarations of variable "x" and "y"

```js
const x = 1;
   

const [y] = [1]
```

What is the meaning of 2nd declaration?
Can someone suggest an article about such declaration type.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

You are unpacking values from arrays or object properties.
In your above code, a `const` variable `y` will be defined with value 1.